# Best way to save JPG images to scale up in web (Css) without losing quality in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, css, image-quality

Any ideas how to save a JPG (or any similar - small (KB) size Format) image with the size of 300px/300px in Photoshop - to scale it up to 600px/600px with using css in a webpage, without loosing "Quality"? I try to figure out wich settings are doing well... And how I can save the images in small sizes (KB)

**1. Saving JPG in Photoshop in 300x300px**

[image]

**2. Scaling up with CSS to 600 x 600px**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to scale up an image without losing quality.

In that case, you should scale your image *down*.

So instead of saving it as 300x300, save it as 600x600. Search for good optimization / compression methods, maybe use PNG instead (because sometimes a PNG-8 compressed can be smaller than a JPEG). You probably need to use a different tool to optimize the PNG file (search the web for "PNG image optimizer")

Better yet, I'd save it as a size in between 300px and 600px, so it's both smaller than 600 and has better quality than 300. You might need to try a few different sizes to find the right balance between quality / file size.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Maybe i will save the images in JPEG (600x600) and optimize them... PNG-8 comes close to the Size as in JPEG but looks worse.  I realized that bigger images wich scaled down are looking great on mobile devices...

Comment: Yes, mostly because the mobile devices have high resolution displays, so scaling down usually works better as well

Answer (score 1):

More to complement Luciano's answer than counter it:

Another thing to take into account is connection speed and bandwidth - you don't want to be firing a massive image over the web if you can get away with it. One option is to have two versions of the image, one acting as a thumbnail and the other as the full-sized image.

Though JPEGs have compression, it's still important to remember: though it *seems* like you're only doubling the size of the image, you're actually quadrupling it. E.g. 600 x 600 = 360,000 pixels, 300 x 300 = 90,000 pixels (then multiply that by 3 or 4 depending on the number of bytes per pixel).

Comment: Size of a compressed jpeg is not so much of a function of number of pixels but rather entropy of the image. Entropy tends to grow with image size but then you can afford to compress more.

Comment: @joojaa: True, but the OP was asking about compression without losing quality. Thankfully PS has a preview mode to show what the image will look like prior to actual compression. I use this to gauge final save quality. The other problem, of course, is detail of the image; a busy picture has far less opportunity for compression without being affected by artefacts (using JPEG or similar lossy compression).